# How does a JDBC driver implement the setMaxRows method

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

According to the JDBC specifications, the [`Statement.setMaxRows(int maxRows)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-) method is supposed to:

> Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any ResultSet
>   object generated by this Statement object can contain to the given
>   number. If the limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently
>   dropped.

When testing it against limiting the result set at the SQL level (ROWSET, TOP and LIMIT), both the JDBC and the SQL construct seem to perform very well.

Even when selecting millions of rows, the `setMaxRows` doesn't seem to perform worse.

Could it be because the database Executor might use a database cursor which only fetches records on demand, so when the driver reaches the `maxRows` threshold, the database can be instructed to close the cursor?

This way, the database doesn't have to select a huge result set and send it to the wire, only to be discarded on the client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, PgJDBC sends a request at the protocol level that is the equivalent of appending a `LIMIT` to the query. So the database server knows to try to minimise the amount of work it does where possible. It might choose a plan that'd be more expensive to fetch all rows, but that can start returning some rows sooner or avoid a big all-rows sort, for example.

I expect client drivers for other engines are similar - set a limit behind the scenes, or use a cursor and read until they have enough results.

Each DBMS and driver will be different, so a single definitive answer might be hard to find.

Comment: `setMaxRows()` is *not* equivalent to using `LIMIT`: `LIMIT` is known at query planning time, while the row limit is only known to the executor. So you can easily end up using an execution plan that is not optimized for fetching the first rows quickly. Also, `setMaxRows()` prevents parallel query execution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The JDBC driver is free to push down the limit to the server in the execution of the SQL. For PostgreSQL there are protocol level hints that can be sent about the number of rows or proportion of rows that the client expects to read. I can't remember the details now (it's been nearly 10 years) but the effect is at least similar, if not identical.

Comment: There is only such a hint for cursors: `cursor_tuple_fraction`, but that also only works at query planning time. I blogged about the problem [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/parallel-query-postgresql-problems-jdbc-dbeaver/).

Answer (score 1):

Most JDBC drivers will fetch rows on demand (based on the fetch size), so usually `maxRows` will be quite efficient. They usually even optimize to simply fetch no more than `maxRows`.

A `ROWS` or `TOP` might give the database server some extra hints for optimizing the query, so setting `maxRows` might not be as efficient as including the max in the query itself. The exact behaviour is driver and database dependent, so it is hard to generalize on behaviour and performance characteristics.

The notable exception is the MySQL driver (and probably also MariaDB) that defaults to fetching **all** rows (unless fetch size is set to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`) immediately on query execution.

As an example in Jaybird (Firebird JDBC driver), the [following](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/blob/master/src/main/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/FBStatementFetcher.java#L176) is done (for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`):

```java
public void fetch() throws SQLException {
    synchronized (syncProvider.getSynchronizationObject()) {
        checkClosed();
        int maxRows = 0;

        if (this.maxRows != 0) maxRows = this.maxRows - rowNum;

        int fetchSize = this.fetchSize;
        if (fetchSize == 0) fetchSize = MAX_FETCH_ROWS;

        if (maxRows != 0 && fetchSize > maxRows) fetchSize = maxRows;

        if (!allRowsFetched && (rows.isEmpty() || rows.size() == rowPosition)) {
            rows.clear();
            stmt.fetchRows(fetchSize);
            rowPosition = 0;
        }

        if (rows.size() > rowPosition) {
            setNextRow(rows.get(rowPosition));
            // help the garbage collector
            rows.set(rowPosition, null);
            rowPosition++;
        } else {
            setNextRow(null);
        }
    }
}
```

As the server may decide to send more rows than requested, additional checks are made on `next()`.

Comment: But even if all rows are fetched, doesn't MySQL use a stream like approach? Does it necessarily fetch all rows in the database memory before starting sending the response over the wire?

Comment: The default MySQL behaviour is to fetch all rows and cache them clientside, see under _ResultSet_: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html . You can use streaming result sets, but that has other implications, because it makes it impossible to use the same connection for executing other statements until all rows have been fetched. I don't know the exact details of how the MySQL protocol works, but as I understand it, as soon as you have executed a query, you will need to read all rows that the query produced; but I am not 100% sure about that.

Comment: According to the docs, that's how it should work, but then it would have to perform equally to a query that doesn't limit the result set. In practice, the performance is more close to using a LIMIT. So, I guess they do something to optimize it.

Comment: I don't know the exact details for MySQL, maybe it is not necessary to read all rows and they can signal the serverside cursor to close when they have fetched `maxRows`. That or maybe the driver rewrites the query to include the limit in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses producer-consumer design pattern. So the rows are generated at the moment when client starts fetching from the cursor into the ResultSet. There are two optimizer goals: ALL_ROWS and FIRST_ROWS(resp. FIRST_ROWS(n)). When using first_rows optimizer goal Oracle tends to use more nested loops over hash_joins, and therefore it should return the first bulk of result data much faster. But I'm not sure whether using setMaxRows method also changes optimizer goal for the query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setMaxRows()`, the PostgreSQL server will stop producing query result after the limit has been reached. So does *not* send all rows to the client.

However, that row limit is only imposed at query execution time, so the PostgreSQL optimizer doesn't know about it and will produce an execution plan that is optimized for fetching the whole result set, rather than a plan the produces the first rows quickly. Moreover, using `setMaxRows()` will prevent parallel query execution, even if the optimizer planned it, which can also result in a suboptimal execution plan.

Prefer an explicit `LIMIT` clause over `setMaxRows()` whenever possible.